# Can't upload junit xml file to JIRA Hosted Server using Zephyr Scale Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira-zephyr

I am trying to send JUnittest xml files from test pipelines in Jenkins, to [Zephyr Scale Plugin][1] on Jira Server. I have configured Jenkins correctly with the connection information and tested the connection.

In Post actions I have used the following configurations to publish the XML result:

```
publishTestResults serverAddress: 'https://jira.me.local/',
projectKey: 'GW',
format: 'JUnit XML Result File',
filePath: 'junitresult.xml',
autoCreateTestCases: false
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[Zephyr Scale] [INFO] Publishing test results...
[Zephyr Scale] [ERROR] There was an error while publishing test results to Zephyr Scale and they were not sent. Error details: 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
Error when executing fixed post condition:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not implemented for Zephyr Scale Server/DC
    at com.adaptavist.tm4j.jenkins.extensions.JiraInstance.publishJUnitFormatBuildResult(JiraInstance.java:99)
    at com.adaptavist.tm4j.jenkins.http.Tm4jJiraRestClient.uploadJUnitXmlResultFile(Tm4jJiraRestClient.java:79)
    at com.adaptavist.tm4j.jenkins.extensions.postbuildactions.TestResultPublisher.uploadResultsFile(TestResultPublisher.java:140)
    at com.adaptavist.tm4j.jenkins.extensions.postbuildactions.TestResultPublisher.validateFieldsAndUploadResults(TestResultPublisher.java:115)
    at com.adaptavist.tm4j.jenkins.extensions.postbuildactions.TestResultPublisher.publishResults(TestResultPublisher.java:94)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.adaptavist.tm4j.jenkins.extensions.postbuildactions.TestResultPublisher.handlePublishException(TestResultPublisher.java:106)
    at com.adaptavist.tm4j.jenkins.extensions.postbuildactions.TestResultPublisher.publishResults(TestResultPublisher.java:96)
    at com.adaptavist.tm4j.jenkins.extensions.postbuildactions.TestResultPublisher.perform(TestResultPublisher.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:100)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:70)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried converting the XML file to json and used the custom format but it gave me

```
{"errorMessages": ["Invalid Custom Format JSON file"]}
```

Anyone has idea?

Links:
[1]: https://plugins.jenkins.io/tm4j-automation/

Comment: Have you found any workaround?

Comment: @Yaryna jenkins plugin doesnt support Jira Sever but only Jira Cloud. You can verify this in https://github.com/jenkinsci/tm4j-automation-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/adaptavist/tm4j/jenkins/extensions/JiraServerInstance.java#L101

Comment: @Yaryna I have moved to XRay.